# viewvc colored side-by-side diffs?

Tags: viewvc

I have inherited management responsibility for a VERY old installation of Subversion (1.4.2) integrated with JIRA (3.6.4!).  The installation includes ViewVC 1.0.3.  This integration has a particularly nice feature of showing colored, side-by-side diffs when displaying code changes.

Upgrading to the latest CollabNet Subversion (5.2.3 x64) is giving me a version of ViewVC that loses this feature - it can do side-by-side diffs, but without highlighting; it can do colored diffs, but not side-by-side.  The side-by-side diffs without color loses something.  The little angle brackets down the center just aren't nearly as easily spotted.  The developers don't like the update, and I really don't blame them.

Is there some way to recover the side-by-side colored diffs feature of (much!) older ViewVC versions?

I'll note that I found this link https://users.viewvc.tigris.narkive.com/4MkBPAje/viewvc-users-viewvc-1-1-6-no-side-by-side-color-diff from 9 years ago.  It did not work for me!  (Though I am considering trying to edit the diff.ezt template, if I can understand it!)